Minimally reproducible diffusion model
I am working on my thesis where I test the speed of sampling from probability distributions of different algorithms.
I also want to integrate the sampling algorithms into some machine learning models that use sampling, i.e. diffusion models.
But my computer is too weak to train on large images and cloud computing is not an option because I can't get the services in my country.
My question is, is there an open source version of a very simple diffusion model that can be trained in a moderate amount of time that doesn't require high processing power?

they are density estimators pretty much, so you just need samples from the same distribution (almost always) to make them work (aka nay dataset)
